# How to make CoreData return only rows that have a relationship?

Tags: core-data

I want my fetchRequest to only return rows that have a relationship that's not nil, but I am having problem forming the predicate for this.  How should this be done?

[Update] I should mention, the relationship is to-many.

Comment: Do you get an answer to that by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relationship is named `myRelation`, a predicate like `self.myRelation != nil` should work.